# Visual Studio 2015, C# : New errors by changing configuration

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, configurationmanager

I have a very strange problem :
I added a new configuration in `visual studio`, based on the debug one.
Thus, when I change the configuration, I have new bugs.

So, if I stay in debug mode, everything works fine.
If I change to another one (Release or my new one, Test), For a specific xaml file,
- I have an issue on "`InitializeComponent`" (It cannot find its definition)
- It cannot load converters I defined in .

Once again, I didn't change any code, and if I switch back to Debug, everything works fine.
I keep the same platform (Any CPU).

Comment: Make sure all your projects are building in the right platform in the Configuration Manager (from the build menu)

Comment: This can happen if you added any references to other projects by pointing directly to their output in the `bin` folder.  When you change configurations things get compiled to different directories and it can no longer find the updated .dll.  Usually solvable by fixing your reference so that they are actual `project` references instead of `file` references.

Comment: Thanks Bradley, I think it was the problem. However, I didn't manage the project/file reference. If I download external dll, I cannot put them as project reference. So I need to load them in each configuration